# How to convert a list of items into a grid of items?

Tags: formatting

How does one change the format from a list of `\item`s into a grid of items:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{resume}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}    

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}

   \section{\mysidestyle Hobbies}
   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3.7mm]
    \renewcommand\labelitemi{--}% < LOCALLY Setting the bullet as an en-dash
    \vspace{0mm}
    \item Chess
    \item Photography
    \item Programming
    \item Travelling
    \item Volunteer work
    \end{itemize}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

For example, the code above generates the following, but how could I convert this:

[image]

into something like this:

[image]

**Edit**
I have used the resume template from https://github.com/sbrother/resume.

Comment: Can you please post a complete, compilable example? It matters a lot which class you're using and which packages, if any, you are using to customise lists.

Comment: @cfr Apologies, new to this exchange. Please find the compilable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple and easy with `tasks` or `shortlst`:    % source of template: https://github.com/sbrother/resume

```
\documentclass[margin, line]{resume}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{shortlst}
    \newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][3]{%
    \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\labelitemi}%
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\parindent+\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%
    \setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/#1-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
   \begin{shortitemize}}%
    {\end{shortitemize}}%

\makeatletter\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \name{\Large 3kstc}
  \begin{resume}

     \section{\mysidestyle Contact\\Information}
         Phone: (\texttt{+}02) 0123 45 67 89 \hfill LinkedIn: \href{https://www.linkedin.com/deadlink/}{https://www.linkedin.com/deadlink} \\
         \noindent Email: noemail@deadlink.com \hfill Address: some street, in some city, of the world\vspace{0mm}\\\vspace{-4.5mm}

     \section{\mysidestyle Hobbies}
       % \leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip }
         \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3.7mm, before = \leavevmode\vspace*{-\parskip}]%
             \renewcommand\labelitemi{--} % < LOCALLY Setting the bullet as an en-dash
                 \vspace{0mm}
                 \item Chess
                 \item Photography
                 \item Programming
                 \item Travelling
             \item Volunteer work
         \end{itemize}

     \section{\mysidestyle Hobbies 2}
     \leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \parsep}%-\parskip
         \begin{tasks}[style = itemize, label = \bfseries\textendash, label-width = 0.8em, item-indent = 1.15em](3)
             \task Chess
             \task Photography
             \task Programming
             \task Travelling
             \task Volunteer work
         \end{tasks}

     \section{\mysidestyle Hobbies 3}%
        \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textendash}
         \begin{tabitemize}[3]
             \renewcommand\labelitemi{--} % < LOCALLY Setting the bullet as an en-dash
                 \vspace{0mm}
                 \item Chess
                 \item Photography
                 \item Programming
                 \item Travelling
             \item Volunteer work
         \end{tabitemize}
  \end{resume}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way I can get "Volunteer work" to appear without a line break i.e in one line?

Comment: Yes. Please see my updated code: I've decreased the value of`item-indent`. Other than that, you can use a smaller font size, or use only two columns of items. Each \task is a `\parbox`  of width the total availabel width divided by the number of columns. Last possibility: a `\task` may occupy two (or more columns). You'll find details in the documentation of the package.

Comment: I've used "\section{\mysidestyle Hobbies}" and now there is a [misalignment](https://i.imgur.com/4fc4xeR.png) - how could I rectify this? I want the first line of items to be in the same line as "Hobbies [2]"?

Comment: I've shared the document template from github, if that helps - I'm new latex, so if there is anything that I could provide, please let me know....

Comment: I get the same misalignment with minipage.

Comment: *Actually*, I get the same misalignment with plain normal text and nothing else. I don't know what's going on, here.

Comment: @Bernard Really appreciate your help, but I can't get the alignment correct, - is there any advice you could share with me?

Comment: I should need the code you actually use. Could you post a minimal code which reproduces the problem? Also, does the code in my answer give the expected result?

Comment: @Bernard [here is the code](https://codeshare.io/5z6q4N) and here is a [snapshot](https://ibb.co/hV4rLc) of the output. I am currently using Texmaker 5.0.2, could you please help me with the [misalignment](https://ibb.co/fnM7RH) - _[Hobbies 3](https://ibb.co/bxtyYx) is the ideal output that I am after_?

Comment: @3kstc: Unfortunately your code has many error messages (loading inputenc, while the class requires compiling with xe/lualatex, resume environment unknown. We need a code which compiles smoothly, but reproduces your alignment problem.

Comment: @Bernard - with me it just [compiles without any problems/errors](https://ibb.co/jazk0c).... (sorry I am new to Latex) - how can I fix the error messages?

Comment: I have reduced the [code down to 37 lines](https://codeshare.io/5z6q4N) hopefully you won't get errors.... :/ Did you by chance install resume.cls?

Comment: NO, it's not a standard package. I've found one `resume.cls` on the web, but the `resume` environment is ‘undefined’, so it must not be the same class. Where did you find it?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry - I might have confused you a bit - What I met to say was did you by chance [download the template](https://github.com/sbrother/resume)? I downloaded the template, and opened the [.tex](https://github.com/sbrother/resume/blob/master/resume.tex) file in [TexMaker 5.0.2](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/shots.html), then compiled it - it worked without any errors :/ - I just changed the content in the sections to  make it relevant to me - and that was it - which didn't yield any errors.

Comment: @3kstc: I think I've finally solved the problem, and I added another solution with the `shortlst` package (which you'll have to install by hand, as it's not part of the classic distributions). Please take a look at my modified answer.

Comment: @Bernard Outstanding! _Hobbies 2_ yields everything perfectly. What was the problem? Would you be able to explain `\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \parsep}%-\parskip` does?  Thank you for all your time, help and effort!

Comment: @3kstc: The `%-\parskip` can be removed – it's a remnant of a previous trial`. As to `leavevmode`: usually at the end of a `\section` command, one is in the so-called `vertical mode`, and had  to switch to `horizontal mode` (the mode for typesetting paragraphs) befora  applying a negative vertical space to raise the beginning of the list to the level of the section title. The amount of vertical spacing which worked well was the sum of a normal interline spacing (`\baselineskip`) and the spacing which is added between paragraphs of an item in a list(`\parsep`).

Answer (score 1):

As you are already using the `enumitem` package if you use `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}` then you can use an "inline itemize" environment with `\begin{itemize*}....\end{itemize*}` to produce:

[image]

To change the item "separator" from a bullet to `--` it is enough to add `label=--` to the `itemize` options. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

   \section{Hobbies}

   \begin{itemize*}[leftmargin=3.7mm]
    \item Chess
    \item Photography
    \item Programming
    \item Travelling
    \item Volunteer work
    \end{itemize*}

   \begin{itemize*}[leftmargin=3.7mm, label=--]
    \item Chess
    \item Photography
    \item Programming
    \item Travelling
    \item Volunteer work
    \end{itemize*}

\end{document}
```

...and the full output:

[image]

[As others have done, I have dropped the `resume.cls` since I don't have it installed.]

**Edit**

As far as I can see `enumitem` does not provide a way to change the spacing between in-line `\items`, however, you can hack this by making the label wider with something like `label={\hspace*{12mm}--}`. (As shown in the next example, you can also use `itemjoin` for this.) For example, the code

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

   \section{Hobbies}
     \begin{itemize*}[label={\hspace*{12mm}--}]
    \item Chess
    \item Photography
    \item Programming
    \item Travelling
    \item Volunteer work
    \end{itemize*}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

As far as I can see, it is not possible to set the number of items per line but with a little more persistence you can fudge this too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\parindent=0pt
\newlist{inlineitemize}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[inlineitemize]{% create a custom in-line list environment
   itemjoin=\itemizenewline,
   label={--}
}
\newcounter{inline}
\newcommand\itemizenewline{% start newline every 4=3+1 columns
   \ifnum\value{inline}=3\setcounter{inline}{0}\newline%
   \else\stepcounter{inline}\hspace{14mm}% 14mm between \items
   \fi%
}

\begin{document}

   \section{Hobbies}
    \begin{inlineitemize}
      \item Chess
      \item Photography
      \item Programming
      \item Travelling
      \item Volunteer work
    \end{inlineitemize}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Note that the "item widths" vary here so the items are unlikely to line up in columns, but if this is what you want you should probably be using an environment like `tabular`.

Comment: thanks, how can I increase the spacing between each of the '\item's

Comment: @3kstc See my edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the documentclass `resume` and I don't know how you defined `\mysidestyle`, so my answer is only useful to that extent, but it might fit your fix and align nicely next to your sidestyle section title. Solution with multicols and minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textsc{Hobbies}
\begin{minipage}[top]{100mm}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{itemize}%[leftmargin=3.7mm]
            \renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
            \vspace{0mm}
            \item Chess
            \item Photography
            \item Programming
            \item Travelling
            \item Volunteer work
        \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Hobbies is misaligned, but you might figure out how to do it properly with `\mysidestyle`. I shamelessly stole `\noindent\textsc{Hobbies}` from Barnard's answer above.

[image: pdf output to posted code]

Comment: thanks, I have shared the source of the document template from [github](https://github.com/sbrother/resume) if that helps with understanding the document - I'm new latex, so if there is anything else that I could provide, please let me know....  I would ideally like the first line to be on the same line with "Hobbies". With yours it appears to be sitting in the middle of the two lines...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't how to prevent "Volunteer work" from breaking across lines with enumitem. I know it looks rather ugly.

Comment: Doesn't look better. Now the hobbies is just *above* the list. The Wikibooks article about minipage says the `[top]` option should make the topmost baselines align, but it seems that's different with list environments and I can't get it to align nicely. Maybe someone with more `lengths` knowledge will be inspired and provide an improved answer. The task aswer is quite nice, though, but it should be tested with `resume.cls`.

Comment: If you replace the `{100mm}` by `{150mm}`, it doesn't break any more, but the whole minipage might become too wide for your text area, depending on the geometry you're using.